# Calibration of OSL dates to calender year dates

Tags: dating, archaeology

I am trying to utilize a function that uses calibrated $^{14}C$ dates. However, my data consists of OSL dates, not $^{14}C$. Searching google scholars did not provide any useful results. Since OSL dates are based on radiation, I presume these do not directly translate to calendar years. Is it possible to calibrate OSL dates into calendar year dates?